# Cross-reference to an entry in the toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, lyx

Is there any way to cross-reference to sections/subsections via their title? I find myself writing "Please see section 4 for more details", and it gets annoying very soon, especially when I have to change the numbers repeatedly.

I am using lyx, so it would be nice if there's some way of automating some of the steps.

Comment: following your edit, I have added the `lyx` tag to your question. Hopefully someone who can help with that part will be along shortly.

Answer (score 6):

Use `\label` and `\ref`.

```
\section{Green's function}
\label{sec:green}
```

...

```
\ref{sec:green}.
```

More details can be found in the [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/), which is worth reading.

The [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package can save you some typing by automatically preceding the reference with section, theorem, equation, etc. as appropriate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\label{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\cref{thm}
\end{document}
```